# Quiero utilizar un metodo de una clase e implementarlo en un boton java netbeans

Tags: java, botón

Tengo una clase con arreglos y **cada arreglo es un alimento** que contiene un `String` *(Nombre del alimento)* y 12 `floats` *(valores nutrimentales del alimento)*, a la vez hice 3 métodos en la misma clase:

1. para imprimirlo
2. para ordenar los arreglos con selectionSort
3. un método compareTo

quiero que esos métodos los pueda utilizar en un botón para que cuando el usuario de `click` en el boton el arreglo salga ordenado en un `jtextArea`

carbAlimentos

```
arregloAlimentos[] = {new Alimentos("Fresas", 2.91f, 0f, 1.85f, 1.67f, 4.10f, 6.13f, 41.25f, .09f, 8.25f, 6.67f, 6.67f, 56.22f)};
```

Con esto ordeno el atributo carb del arreglo correspondiente:

```
public static void selectionSort(Alimentos[] arreglo){
           for (int i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
               int min = i;
               for (int j = i + 1; j < arreglo.length; j++) {
                   if(arreglo[j].carb < arreglo[min].carb){
                       min = j;
                   }
               }
               Alimentos temp =  arreglo[i];
            arreglo[i] = arreglo[min];
            arreglo[min] = temp;
           }
```

quiero implementarlo en este boton de un `jFrameform`:

```
private void btnCarbohidratosActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 


}
```

Comment: Colocar urgente no hará que recibas ayuda mas rápido, a parte que se ve un poquito con exigencia y mal

Comment: Bienvenido seas, por favor date una vuelta por [ask] y de paso realiza el [tour], saludos.

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. Qué te impide llamar a la función dentro del ActionPerformed del botón? Si el objeto de la clase donde tienes la función es visible, lo podrá ejecutar, como cualquier otra función. Falta código y explicación en tu pregunta para poder ayudarte. Piensa en qué le haría falta a alguien para poder ayudarte y sobre todo piensa en que solo tú entiendes y conoces tu código.

Answer (score 0):

Si entiendo bien lo que quieres, recomiendo que cambies tu método `void` por un `String` y concatenes el resultado.

```
public static String selectionSort(Alimentos[] arreglo){
    String result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
        int min = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < arreglo.length; j++) {
            if(arreglo[j].carb < arreglo[min].carb){
                min = j;
            }
        }
        Alimentos temp =  arreglo[i];
        arreglo[i] = arreglo[min];
        arreglo[min] = temp;
        result += temp+","
    }
    return result;
}
```

ahora para cuando hace click el usuario y el resultado se muestre en un `jTextArea`

```
private void btnCarbohidratosActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
    String resultado = selectionSort(arregloAlimentos);
    jTextAreaExample.setText(resultado);
}
```